# Text file to mysql with conditional logics

Tags: php, mysql

I have a word list in this format

```
input n 4 2 @ ~ 4 1 07279488 06777755 05836008 03578305
```

1. word = input
2. word_type = n
3. Sense_number = 4 this is variable from 1 to x
4. link_number= 2 - this is variable from 1 to x. 2 means next 2 symbols are the links. if the number is 3 next 3 symbols are the links at number5
5. Links= @ ~
6. Synset_number= 4 is the same with sense number and means after the next field 4 block are the synset ids at number 8
7. tag_number= 1 has 1 tag
8. synset_ids= 07279488 06777755 05836008 03578305

How we can insert these text rows with conditional logics?

Comment: ı can do normal text row inserting. problem is in this text line there is conditions. and i have no idea on that.

Comment: What's the problem? Just use `if` statements.

Comment: I don't see any conditions. Are you talking about the variable number of columns? Just use loops.